# Can I get calendar meetings out of MS Teams?

Tags: microsoft-teams

I want to find if you can programmatically get calendar information out of MS Teams.

I was searching but didn't find any information, as with any documentation related to Microsoft you can't find anything useful.

So What I need any of:

- some kind of WebHook, maybe that will run my script when new even is added to my calendar.
- MS Teams call my script the meeting.
- API that will allow exporting events from the calendar, so I can use a cron job to sync with the app I plan to create.

Basically, I was thinking about this tool [ntfy](https://github.com/binwiederhier/ntfy). But I don't want to use MS Teams app for my phone if there is one, because I would like to have an app that will integrate with MS teams and Google Calendar. That I have to use at work. I'm a contractor for a software company that has a client that I'm working for. I need to use MS teams for a software company and Google Calendar for the client. Also, I can't log in with my work Google account, because it's blocked for the security of google drive (this at least was the error message). So my own Android app is the only way to have notifications on my phone (I need it because I sometimes forget about the meetings).

How I should create something like this? I only need general advice about integration with MS Teams. What API should I use? Will ask about Google Calendar in another question.

Note that I have zero knowledge about MS Teams, was searching for some developer documentation but was not able to find anything that can be useful for the thing I need.

I don't have any code yet, I'm investigating possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

You could use so-called "graph api", the api Microsoft promotes to interact with anything related to Microsoft, including teams. There is simply a method to get all events for a team (i.e. group):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/calendar-list-events

There is an online sandbox you could use to play with it:

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer